# How to use user-provided CUDA toolkits?

Tags: cudalink, gpu

In the [revision history](https://www.wolfram.com/language/quick-revision-history.html), Mathematica v12.1 claims to have "support for user-provided CUDA Toolkits". But other than this line in the revision history, I cannot find any other reference to this feature. When I install CUDA resources, the CUDA toolkit being used is still the one shipped with the paclet (v10.2), not CUDA toolkit v11.1 that I installed.

Is there a way to use user-provided CUDA toolkits in Mathematica?